# Return the address of a static const variable in C

Tags: c, function, static, constants, memory-address

Is it safe to return the address of a static const variable in C like below?

```
uint8_t *return_static_const_addr(void)
{
    static const uint8_t values[2] = {0x01, 0x02};

    return values;
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider returning a `const` qualified pointer: `const uint8_t *return_static_const_addr(void)`

Comment: Depends on the context. It is safe in the sense it does not violate anything. It might be not safe with certain usages.

Comment: It's safe, but it's probably poor design.

Comment: But you are aware that returning the address of a non static local variable will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will have a constant address during the runtime, so, yes it's safe.

Answer (score -1):

The static const variable here is local variable so it would not be stored on the stack and therefore are generally not thread safe. It also depends on the compiler. Returning static const variable would be safe if you were writing this, say for example, for C++11, where such kind of dynamic initialization of a local static is thread-safe.

Comment: C++ is not a compiler but a different language not really relevant to this question. So  no, in C it does not depend on compiler.

Comment: `static` local variables have static storage duration same as global variables, so they have to be thread safe same as global ones.

Comment: @EugeneSh. C++ is indeed a language. I gave an example of C++11 which extends the standard C++ library and where the usage of static const variable could be safe to use.

Comment: The question is tagged with C, _not_ with C++.